# Function field of $\mathbb{G}_m^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

We assume our base field $k$ is algebraically closed, so any $k$-torus is split. As in the heading above, for $n = 1, \mathbb{G}_m$ is a rational variety and so its function field is $k(t)$ for an indeterminate $t$. Is the function field of $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ simply $k(t_1,...,t_n)$? In other words, are $n$-dimensional tori $k$-rational varieties?

When $k$ is not algebraically closed, this is not true. But it still holds for $n=1$, since up to isomorphism we only have two $1$-dimensional tori. They are the trivial torus and the one given by Weil restriction of a two-dimensional extension of the base field.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ not an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$? You have more than one torus in dimension $1$, you have one for each separable quadratic extension. IIrc, there are entire papers about rationality questions about tori: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.4525.pdf

Comment: You might also want to see Chapter 2 of: https://www.ams.org/books/mmono/179/

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for your references, it turns out that rationality also holds for $n=2$. But maybe my question should've been, are tori geometrically rational? Since I am only concerned about torus over algebraically closed fields. Yes, $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, and I believe it is dense too. I guess this trivially shows that $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ is birational to $\mathbb{A}^n$ and therefore to $\mathbb{P}^n$? Maybe my question was (again) poor.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's correct. Having the same function field is trivially true for open subsets of varieties, so it holds trivially for $\mathbb{G}_m^n$. Glad it helped.